# graph of dependent income

Tags: microeconomics, mathematical-economics, utility, supply-and-demand, consumer-theory

I would need help with the following problem about consumer theory. Let us say that $X$ is the amount of days at the sea and $Y$ is the amount of days on the cottage. We have some utility function $u(X,Y)$ and constraint $ 4X+9Y=I$. I have found the optimal solution $(X^{\star}=\frac{I}{5},Y^{\star}=\frac{I}{3})$ and I am supposed to graphically illustrate and comment dependence $X^{\star}$ and $Y^{\star}$ on income $I$. I am not sure if i understand exactly the task. Could you help me with the solution? Thank you.

Comment: I feel like X should be the amount of days at the sea and Y should be the amount of days on the cottage and then you should have some some utility function $U(X,Y)$ which you can express with indifference curves.

Comment: I have changed the task, would you know now?